# Problems Calculating and Grouping Results Accurately with timediff

Tags: group-by, sum

Query Function
 time_to_sec (TIMEDIFF(`ohrm_attendance_record`.`punch_out_user_time`,`ohrm_attendance_record`.`punch_in_user_time`))/3600 AS time_to_sec_TIMEDIFF_ohrm

Results should total to 4.35 Right? but for some reason I cannot get a group total for the records when I use that query function and I would like to get the group total for those results.

The closest I can come to the right total is with this next query function:  It at least does total the records but goes not give me the desired result:

CAST(SUM(timediff(punch_out_user_time,punch_in_user_time))AS time) AS totalhours   This comes up with a total of 04:21:00

I surely need to get this stuff calculated so I can report payable time accurately.

Im Stumped. P.S Any Suggestions?
Here are some results from first query.
The Calc:
time_to_sec (TIMEDIFF(`ohrm_attendance_record`.`punch_out_user_time`,`ohrm_attendance_record`.`punch_in_user_time`))/3600 AS time_to_sec_TIMEDIFF_ohrm

The Results:

6   brk ADJ- Time showed 9:18  Adjusted to 8:53.
Updated by Steve - Please be sure to verify that you punched out successfully and keep a written timesheet as backup. 1st Occurance.
    continue inputting  2015-07-11 06:48:00 2015-07-11 08:53:00 6   2.0833
6   brk Continue inputting  2015-07-11 09:22:00 2015-07-11 10:23:00 6   1.0167
6   brk continue lahaina divers     2015-07-11 10:32:00 2015-07-11 10:46:00 6   0.2333
6   stop for now, still need to continue with lahaina divers drift divers   continue inputting lahaina divers   2015-07-11 11:00:00 2015-07-11 12:01:00 6   1.0167

Here are some more results:  The Calc
 CAST(SUM(timediff(punch_out_user_time,punch_in_user_time))AS time) AS totalhours

The Results
6   brk ADJ- Time showed 9:18  Adjusted to 8:53.
Updated by Steve - Please be sure to verify that you punched out successfully and keep a written timesheet as backup. 1st Occurance.
    continue inputting  2015-07-11 06:48:00 2015-07-11 08:53:00 6   04:21:00
Thats it.
Help!

Comment: Mind to align you question parts as according to the editor used in this site? Then I can read it and maybe understand (especially line 1 is interesting: 4:35: You do not mention any data before that line, so it can be anything if it is up to me.

Comment: Haha,  I see your point.   I will revisit this.